# can you add plugins to a phonegap build project?

Tags: cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to use Phonegap's Build service to build projects that may have plugins that require a edited .xml or extra files that Build normally doesn't ask for? I am assuming it will only compile the .html and .js/.css files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on build only child browser is support with the cloud build

Comment: What does this answer even mean?

Comment: It means that only the child browser plugin can be added to your project if your using the phonegap Build site to compile your project

Answer (score -1):

> I am assuming it will only compile the .html and .js/.css files.

No. It is more than compiling of .html and .js/.css. Cordova also connects to native mobile features through plugins. Infact all the [API reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/index.html) provided by Cordova is a plugin with respect to a particular platform. So you can develop your own plugin and use it as per your needs. To develop a plugin you need to refer this

[http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android [For Android]](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)

[http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS[For iOS]](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS)

[http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How%20To%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks[For BB]](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How%20To%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks)

Comment: I mean compile a app with phonegap build cloud